# Ruby On Rails error during run the project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

[image]

I have cloned this project from gitlab , I tried to run this in locally but i cant able to run, when I tried to  install bundle, this error is coming that i mentioned in above picture. Please some one help me to run this project, i have installed railsinstaller to run the project... Is there any other tool need to run big project ??

Comment: You're missing some headers to compile the gem, and the necessary part of log is above

Comment: sorry i cant able to get your point, can u please explain briefly ??? That error showing in this C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.2.0\lib\ruby\gems\2.2.0\extensions\x86-mingw32\2.2.0\kgio-2.11.0\gem_make.out  field....

Answer (score 0):

As the error message clearly states you need to install a gem called kgio before doing bundle install.

So do this

```
gem install kgio -v 2.11.0
```

Then run `bundle install`

Comment: gem install kgio -v '2.11.0` did this succeed?

You can verify it by `gem list` command

Comment: No its not successfully installed...when i installed this it throwing this error

Comment: C:\Sites\zeeno>gem install kgio -v '2.11.0`
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Requirement::BadRequirementError)
    Illformed requirement ["2.11.0`"]

Comment: gem install kgio -v 2.11.0 
try without quotes

Comment: without quotes I am able to install the gem, let me know if that works

Comment: Gem files will remain installed in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/kgio-2.11.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.2.0/kgio-2.11.0/gem_make.out

Comment: im facing the above mentioned error in kgio install

Comment: hai r u there ?//